# PhpStorm Reformat Comments Automatically?

Tags: comments, phpstorm

Is there any way for PhpStorm to automatically reformat all comments in my project? I've already changed the settings to use one-line comments but it doesn't seem to do anything when I run the code formatter.

For example, let's say I have the following comment:

```
    /*
     * Hello, I am a comment
     */
```

Is there any way for PhpStorm to auto-convert it to this:

```
    // Hello, I am a comment
```

I'd also want it to work for multi-line comments i.e.:

```
    /*
     * Hello, I am a comment
     * I'm on multiple lines
     */
```

Should become this:

```
    // Hello, I am a comment
    // I'm on multiple lines
```

Is it possible for PhpStorm to do this for my entire project automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ended up doing a regex replace:

```
find: \/\*\n(.*)\* (.*)\n(.*)\*\/
replace: // $2
```

That worked for my first comment, the one with multiple lines I just changed manually.